# Perform Javascript action after reset button handles click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, reset

How do I perform an action immediately **after** an `<input type="reset"/>` has already reset the form elements?

Comment: How about adding a `onclick` handler to the input?

Comment: HTMLFormElement.onreset will work nicely. Link: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents

Comment: It's generally bad practice to include a reset button at all.  Users often click them accidentally and lose all their work.  In practice, it's very rare that anyone really wants to reset the form.

Comment: @Mrchief: That fires before, not after.
@Matt: Yup, thanks!
@jimbojm: Yeah but the person who wants this page says he wants a reset button, so that's not much of a choice on my part. :P Thanks though.

Comment: @jimbojw? Yours is a very bold statement. You might be interested in [this discussion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/1070/116190) on the UX StackExchange community about reset buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forms have a `reset` event that you can listen for.

```
<script>
function resetHandler() {
    // code
}
</script>
<form ... onreset="resetHandler();">
</form>
```

Of course, it's bad practice to add javascript handlers this way, so you'd want to use `.addEventListener/.attachEvent` or `jQuery.bind()`, but you get the idea.

Comment: resetHandler runs before the form is reset, not after!

Comment: The questions is about the execution of a function AFTER the reset is done, not before, not at the same time. this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 15):

Try :

```
<input type="reset" onclick="return resetForm();"/>

function resetForm(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do whatever
    }, 50);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 for delaying the function to fire *after* the form was reset.

Comment: For every browser I tested, setting the timeout to 0 was sufficient.

Comment: Looks like this is the only way to run something really after the reset

Comment: actually, you don't need the 50 ms, just the timeout is deferring this process to the end of the js processing pile.

Answer (score 2):

Write code/events which you wanted to call in middle of this function. I have tested this. Working good.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:reset").click(function() {       // apply to reset button's click event
        this.form.reset();                    // reset the form

        // call your functions to be executed after the reset      

         return false;                         // prevent reset button from resetting again
    });
});
```

Comment: The [reset function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) fails when a form control has the name or id 'reset'

Answer (score -1):

You always can use jQuery, or do some tricks with form reset event itself.